# Use of the term "normal section" in a theorem of Maria Lucido.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, finite-groups, definition

Prop. 3 in [this paper](http://www.bdim.eu/item?fmt=pdf&id=BUMI_2002_8_5B_1_131_0) (p.135) states

> Let $G$ be a solvable group with $\text{diam}\Gamma(G)=4$.  Then either $l_F(G)\leq 3$ or $l_F(G)=4$ and $G$ has a normal section isomorphic to $H$.

($H$ is a group defined earlier on the page, which I think is isomorphic to [$2O$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_octahedral_group).)

Terminology question: What does exactly does *normal section* mean?  I believe that a section of $G$ is a factor group of some subgroup of $G$ (or at least that's what [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_%28group_theory%29) tells me).

The following paraphrases the usage of the term in her proof on the following page:

> $\text{Fit}_2(G)/\text{Fit}(G)$ is either a cyclic group or the product of a cyclic group of odd order with $Q_{2^n}$.  $\,\,\,\,\,\ldots\,\,\,\,\,$ If $n=3$, $G/\text{Fit}_2(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the product of an abelian group with $S_3$.  $\,\,\,\,\,\ldots\,\,\,\,\,$If $G/\text{Fit}_2(G)$ contains a normal subgroup isomorphic to $S_3$, then $H$ is a normal section of $G$.

So I think this means that $H$ is a subgroup of $G/\text{Fit}(G)$, which seems to imply that normal section means a subgroup of a factor group of $G$.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have have thoguht that a normal section of a group $G$ is a quotient group
$M/N$ where $M$ and $N$ are both normal subgroups of $G$ with $N < M$.

I have looked at the paper, and my interpretation is consistent with what is proved there. I think the group $N$ here is not (necessarily) ${\rm Fit}(G)$ but rather the complete inverse image in $G$ of the normal cyclic subgroup of odd order in ${\rm Fit_2}(G)/{\rm Fit}(G)$. In the situation where the Fitting length is 4, $G/{\rm Fit}_2(G)$ has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $S_3$, and $M$ is the complete inverse image in $G$ of that normal subgroup.